# Remove integer on a list if it is smaller than the previous integer on the list

Tags: python, list

I have an unordered list of numbers

```
num_list=[3 4 5 1 2 5 6 3 1 2 6 9]
```

I want to run through the list and remove all numbers that are smaller than the previous such that the list is ordered in ascending order after deleting such numbers. How can I do that?

Expected output:

```
num_list=[3 4 5 5 6 6 9]
```

Comment: have you made any attempt?

Comment: iterate through the list check condition, `if num[i] < num[i+1]: del num_list[i+1]`

Answer (score 4):

One simple approach would be to iteratively add values from `num_list` to a new list if they satisfy the condition of being greater than the last appended value:

```
out = [num_list[0]]
for i in num_list[1:]:
    if i >= out[-1]:
        out.append(i)
```

---

```
print(out)
# [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Great ! thanks for sharing this simplistic solution

Answer (score 0):

Short approach with `functools.reduce` function:

```
import functools

num_list = [3,4,5,1,2,5,6,3,1,2,6,9]
res = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x if y < x[-1] else x + [y],
                       num_list[1:], [num_list[0]])
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach using `list.pop`

```py
num_list = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]

i = 1

while (i < len(num_list)):
    if num_list[i] < num_list[i - 1]:
        num_list.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1

print(num_list)

# [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

A comprehension could be used for this:

```
num_list = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]
(x for i, x in enumerate(num_list) if all(x >= j for j in num_list[:i]))
```

Though it's not as efficient as yatu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Version with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

num_list=[3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9]

out = [num_list[0]]
[out.extend(g) for v, g in groupby(num_list[1:], lambda k: k>=out[-1]) if v]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one-liner solution using `itertools.accumulate`.

```
from itertools import accumulate
result = [n for n, cur_max in zip(l, accumulate(l, max)) if n >= cur_max]
```

Despite being concise, it is actually much less efficient than the following solution using an explicit `for` loop. This is also the most efficient solution as of now.

```
cur_max = l[0]
result = []
for e in l:
    if e >= cur_max:
        cur_max = e
        result.append(e)
```